# How to access configuration properties in spring webflow in cas-login flow

Tags: cas, spring-webflow-2

This might be a very simple Spring EL question. I have defined a new end-state in cas login-flow as follows:

https://myhost:8443/mymodule/somepage" />

We need to use a URL defined in cas.properties instead of hard coding the URL in externalRedirect new name. Is it possible to use something

and define myurl in cas.properties.

We are usign CAS 3.5.2

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled the same problem, but found a much nicer solution.

```
<view-state id="orderExternalView" view="externalRedirect:#{propertyConfigurer.getProperty('link.externalOrderView')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the solution that you are looking for, but I made it work with a bean defined in `cas-servlet.xml`.

```
<bean id="loadUrls" class="yourpackage.LoadUrls" c:url="${cas.property.myUrl}"/>
```

Then, in the `LoadUrls` class I have the following code:

```
public class LoadUrls{
    private String url;

    public LoadUrls(String url) {
        this.url= url;
    }

    public void loadUrlsFromWebflow(RequestContext context) {
        // [I used flowScope, you can use any other if you want]            
        context.getFlowScope().put("urlWebflow", this.url);
    }
}
```

The last thing you need is to invoke this method from the webflow:

```
<action-state id="stateLoadUrl">
    <evaluate expression="loadUrls.loadUrlsFromWebflow(flowRequestContext)"/>
    <transition to="redirectAction"/>
</action-state>

<end-state id="redirectAction" view="externalRedirect:#{flowScope.urlWebflow}"/>
```

This is just an idea, you can tweak it to fit your needs. An by the way, if you find the solution using just an EL Spring expression, let me know, because I need the same exact thing!

Comment: Thanks. I used a simple work around because I needed something without code development. I passed the URL in request parameters and used the request parameter in end-state.